# Why generated ViewDataBinding class annotates property for "include" tag as Nullable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm using Android Data Binding library to bind an xml layout that has an `<include>`

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.example.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    ...

    <include
        layout="@layout/someOtherLayout"
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout" />
    ...

</layout>
```

In the generated Databinding class for the xml I see this property:

```
@Nullable
public final com.example.databinding.SomeOtherLayoutBinding includedLayout;
```

Why is it annotated as `@Nullable`? The `<include>` is in the layout and as I see it, it is obviously non-null. What am I missing?

It forces me to use non-null assertion operator `!!` in Kotlin code when accessing the fields of the included layout and I'm wondering if it is safe or if there is something I'm not considering here

```
val binder = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)
val someView = binder.includedLayout!!.someView
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the Documentation on View Binding, when you have multiple layouts for configuration changes, if the view is only present in some configurations, the binding class will be marked as nullable.

[View Binding Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: _when_ you have multiple layouts, what was weirding me out is that the include was marked as nullable even though I didn't have multiple layouts, just one. I don't think what you're quoting from the docs applies here.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of databinding compiler (3.1.0) to resolve that issue with nullable bindings of included layouts you could set

`android.databinding.enableV2=true`

in **gradle.properties** file inside your project.

After that you need invoke rebuild. After that all included layout bindings will be marked with `@NonNull` annotation.

Comment: thanks for the input but this doesn't really answer my question, I was asking _why_ they're marked as nullable